# How to add my facebook app to my fan page?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm new to facebook app development and i cant seem to figure this out.  I have a simple app i made (an iframe website) that i want to add to a tab on my facebook page.  When i try to click on the + tab to add it to my page i only have a few options of youtube, events, fbml...  When i do a search absolutely nothing comes up unless i search for those items i just mentioned before (youtube, events, fbml).

Answer (score 2):

Type this into your browser's url bar with the appropiate ids.  (I already assume you have configured the app settings for page tab urls,etc).

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL`

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ for a full explanation.